# Any suggestions on how to improve this "Vertical-align Element Tag" code?

Tags: jquery, javascript-objects

This code first calculates the height of a window, then it centers an Element in the center of the window by applying padding to the parent element of the selected Element.

I just think the code is quite verbose and I hope there is a better way of achieving this goal WITHOUT totally rewriting the code!?

```
$(function(){

    "use strict";

    var wheight = $(window).height();

    var programs = {

        fullScreen : function(stretch) {
            $(stretch).css('height', wheight);  
        },//fullScreen Method

        centerBoxVertical : function(boxSlector) {
            var boxHeight = $(boxSlector).height(),
                paddingTop = parseFloat($(boxSlector).css('padding-top')),
                paddingbottom = parseFloat($(boxSlector).css('padding-bottom')),
                totalBoxHeight = boxHeight + paddingTop + paddingbottom,
                newPaddingTopBottom = (wheight - totalBoxHeight)/2;
                $(boxSlector).parent().css('padding-top',newPaddingTopBottom);
        }//centerBoxVertical Method

    }// programs Object

    programs.fullScreen('.fullheight')
    programs.centerBoxVertical('#rooms .room .content');
    programs.centerBoxVertical('.fullheight .hgroup');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

 "use strict";
 $(boxSlector).css({"position":"fixed","top":"50%","transform":"translateY(-50%)"});

});
```